# AzureAppServiceSettings failing while setting connection string for our DB

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I'm facing an issue where I keep getting this error on our Azure Devops instance while running our yaml pipeline using the task AzureAppServiceSettings@1 to setup the connection strings for our DB server.

```
- task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
  displayName: 'Dev app service settings'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '**subscriptionName**'
    appName: '**appName**'
    resourceGroupName: '**resourceGroupName**'
    connectionStrings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "DefaultConneciton",
          "value": "Server=tcp:**serverName**,1433;Initial Catalog=**dbName**;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=\"Active Directory Default\";",
          "type": "SQLAzure",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]
```

After running the task it throws this error:

> ##[error]Error: Failed to update App service 'appName' Connection Strings. Error: BadRequest - The parameter properties has an invalid
> value. (CODE: 400)

I've also tried editing the app settings through Azure Resource Explorer
And had the same output:

```
{
    "Code": "BadRequest",
    "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value.",
    "Target": null,
    "Details": [
        {
            "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value."
        },
        {
            "Code": "BadRequest"
        },
        {
            "ErrorEntity": {
                "ExtendedCode": "51008",
                "MessageTemplate": "The parameter {0} has an invalid value.",
                "Parameters": [
                    "properties"
                ],
                "Code": "BadRequest",
                "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value."
            }
        }
    ],
    "Innererror": null
}
```

I'm being able to edit the connection string only trough the portal.

Comment: Can you try passing the value to `Authentication field` in connection String in Single Quotes('') and check

Comment: I've tryied that and had the same issue, I've also tryied with some fake string like setting it up to "value": "test", and it fails too

Comment: `Authentication=Active Directory Default` should work. MS Doc does not show any quotes in the connectionstring : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication

Answer (score 0):

if you have added the connection Strings parameter on the azure portal, try to remove it on the pipeline or on the azure portal.

if it doesn't work, replace the ** with the ''.

Comment: The ** are to hide sensitive information, it's like a placeholder to where the data should be set. In the real pipeline I don't have any **